# Laravel Google App Engine - file_put_contents(/tmp/framework/sessions/r3SSHndYkTT0CZA2fU.....)

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, session, storage

Thank you in advance,

I have set up an `app.yaml` file too

after deployment I got `file_put_contents(/tmp/framework/sessions/r3SSHndYkTT0CZA2fUhBJ2i28qWj5qjNxdvZj4wB): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error while I have also created tmp folder and it's subfolder as same as what is inside `/storag`e folder with write permission, but still I am getting above error

`app.yaml` file looks like below

```
runtime: php 
env: flex
runtime_config:
 document_root: public
skip_files:
 - .env
env_variables:
 APP_NAME: Demo
 APP_ENV: local 
 APP_KEY: base64:991ihCoj56qE2RiLqaf+LnBdOBfPzaER2cd4d5d4d4 
 APP_DEBUG : true
 APP_URL: https://demo.ue.r.appspot.com
 APP_STORAGE: /tmp
 VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
 CACHE_DRIVER: file

 SESSION_DRIVER: file
 SESSION_LIFETIME: 120
 APP_LOG: daily
 APP_TIMEZONE: UTC

 DB_CONNECTION: mysql
 DB_HOST: DB_HOST
 DB_DATABASE: DB_DATABASE
 DB_USERNAME: DB_DATABASE
 DB_PASSWORD: DB_PASSWORD
 DB_SOCKET: "DB_SOCKET"

 QUEUE_DRIVER: database

 MAIL_DRIVER: smtp
 MAIL_HOST: smtp.googlemail.com
 MAIL_PORT: 465
 MAIL_USERNAME: MAIL_USERNAME
 MAIL_PASSWORD: MAIL_USERNAME

 LOG_DELETE:  true 
 GOOGLE_VISION_PROJECT_ID : GOOGLE_VISION_PROJECT_ID

beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: demo-db
```

Answer (score 1):

Do follow these steps.

1. Give permission to your **storage** folder. (Read, write)
2. Give permission to your **bootstrap** folder(Read, write)
3. Delete **config.php** file inside `bootstrap >> cache >> config.php`

Run below command to clear the `config:cache`

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

If your `tmp` directory instead of storage give full `read,write` permission. clear the caches.

Comment: tmp is at the same level where app, bootstrap, resources folder is located or have to put inside /storage folder?

Comment: Please check is there is `framework >> sessions` folder inside tmp? give full permission, and clear the caches.

Comment: Yes i have manually created framework >> sessions inside /tmp

Comment: I have moved tmp into the /storage folder and the error has been removed but now i am getting SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` error while i have setup the credentials in the app.yaml

Comment: Looks like an error when setting up the database. Are you using using GAE Standard, Flexible? Cloud SQL for MySQL, PostgreSQL? I think you might find the following [community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard#set_up_database_sessions) to be useful. Notice that depending the version of Laravel you are using you might need to manually add the `DB_SOCKET` value to `config/database.php`. For any additional questions please add a [minimum, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) taking away any PII.

Comment: Hello @DanielOcando, thank you for your help, I have edited my question and added app.yaml file contents, I am using flexible environment, having MySQL 5.7 database, for the DB_SOCKET i think there is a unix_socket array key in config/database.php file or have to something else?, i also removed .env

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by **I have also created tmp folder and it's subfolder as same as what is inside /storage folder with write permission**. Where did you create these files? the issue seems for me in session handling so either you use App Engine standard which us memcache for this case or use app engine flex with some database as per @DanielOcando example to perserve your sessions because App Engine instances are volatile and they maybe shut down at anytime. so if you are saving your sessions on the instance itself with some folder then you would have such issues